# Cannot access theano shared variable

Tags: theano

I created a number of shared variables and placed them in an array like so:

`self.params = [self.We, self.Wr, self.Wv, self.b]`

When I tried to get their value in another part of the code, something like this:

`self.h = [theano.shared(value=p.get_value()*0.) for p in self.params]`

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'get_value'

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: could you give your full code, what is 'p'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that eventhough I used the shared api, I also cast to a float32 with `.astype(theano.config.floatX)` , and this was causing the conversion from sharedVariable to just tensorVariable

Comment: Got the same problem. Thanks a lot! The code would be something like: `self.shared_variable= theano.shared(np.array(some_numpy_array, dtype=theano.config.floatX), name="variable1").astype(theano.config.floatX)`